# DefinedTypes property throws an error when an assembly is loaded from memory dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-assembly

I'm trying to load some of my project's assemblies dynamically.

When I load them via their file path like `Assembly.LoadFile(path)` I can get theirs defined types by calling `GetTypes()` method from loaded assembly.

```
var asm = Assembly.LoadFile(path);
var defienedTypes = asm.GetTypes(); //I've got all types without any error
```

But when I load them from memory like `Assembly.Load(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path))`, I'm not able to retrieve defined types. So calling `GetTypes()` method causes an error:

> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information

And LoaderExceptions property contains all defined types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure all required references used by the assembly are loaded correctly.

'LoaderException' property in Exception object tells you which types are not retrievable.

Comment: yep, you right, I was missing a required assembly. thanks